# What is my name? Simple puzzle

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, chemistry

I am a chemical element .---- -----

I am your ..-. .-. .. . -. -..

Combine them together now I am a country

What is my name?

Comment: I was really hoping for Argentina - argent from argentum (silver, also where Argentina got its name) and then your friend Tina! I knew it wasn't the answer, but was the first one to come to mind. Also "Xx" is the *symbol* for a chemical element.

Comment: Yeah, it was good! Chemists will be (often unknowingly) pedantic about chemistry, ya know, just like anyone who has some concentrated field of study.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Nepal

Because:

> The Morse codes are 10, and FRIEND
>  The 10th element is Ne(on), and a friend is a pal

Comment: Correct! 

Comment: Oh, Morse code. Jeez. I looked at it and I thought it was some kind of advanced, abstract representation of the chemical structure of the element in question, and I’d have to go find out what elements could be described has having those two structures… Way to go for the low-hanging fruits.