# Help me, help my best friend please

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, visual

My best friend Jessica, who is also my roomie has been M.I.A  for a month now. Every 3 lettered agency in a suit has been here harassing me for information on her whereabouts. I have absolutely no idea where she is or what she has done. I am scared and worried about her.

I received an anonymous letter in the mail today. It was supposedly mailed 6 months ago, but 6 months ago she was home. The letter is signed - Gomes. All I can think of is Jessica Gomes the model, because that's what I used to call my friend since they look alike. The mail has series of printed pictures. I have absolutely no idea what it is or if it even means anything. If anyone out there could figure it out that'd be of great help.

Anyways this is what the letter looks like

> Bring my coco besos
>
> .-.. .- -
>
> 1. [image]
> 2. mortem 
>     [image]
>      .
> 3. [image]
>      01001010 01101111 01101000 01101110 00100000 01000100 01101111 01100101 #59
> 4. [image]
>
> .-.. --- -. --.
>
> 1. Hurry up, we're dreaming
> 2. USS WALKE
> 3. [image]
> 4. [image]
>
>    -Gomes

She also only uses Chanel lipsticks and calls them Coco, so I am for certain this letter is from Jessica.
I checked all her lipsticks for some kind of notes and I found one with usb [image] I think Jessica wants me to bring this thing somewhere, but I don't know where??

Hint 1:

> set 1 (3) [image]

Hint 2:

> Set 2 (3) [image]

Comment: [cryptic-clues] are a specific style of crossword-esque clues: please read tag descriptions before using them, and edit your post with applicable tags.

Comment: Never mind where Jessica wants you to bring her lipstick -- where on earth are *you*?

Comment: @PeregrineRook Using the demonym for her surname isn't a malapropism

Answer (score 2):

Bring my coco besos

> Coco = Chocolate
>  Besos = Kisses (spanish)
>  Bring my chocolate kisses. which makes sense with the chocolate lipstick. I choose to ignore this as just being clarification that Jessica has indeed been taken.

.-.. .- -

> Translates to LAT

.-.. --- -. --.

> becomes LONG

So putting those things together

> It looks like you're finding coordinates for the location (LATitude and LONGitude) and each picture is a number.

I suck at pictures, but it looked interesting and i wanted to help.

Here's what i've got from the pictures so far

Set 1

> 1) I actually know this movie. It's 28 months later!
>  2) Barry Howard, dies age 78
>  3) So it's a picture of Charles Mason, the binary translates to `John Doe` and the word Jane Doe and 59 relate him to the 59th victim Reet Jurvetson
>  4) This is UFC 186
>  So the numbers are 287859186

Set 2

> 1) This is an album by m83
>  2) USS WALKE has 3 versions of the ship 34, 416, and 723 - The picture is of a Sennheiser HD 598 headphones
>  3) Heritage Middle School... it's a k12? Not sure what to do with this one.
>  So the numbers MIGHT be 833459812. I picked 34 for the ship so it will have the same number of digits as the first part.

Using those coordinates I land in...

> Nepal? http://www.latlong.net/c/?lat=28.7859186&long=83.3459812

Problems I have so far

> The #59 seems to obvious. It doesn't connect anything else. Three ships, which numbers? What do I do with the high school?

Perhaps it's more date-based as Wesley has mentioned. I may try that at a future time.

Comment: For all the images for the LAT part, I think it's related to the time / date. 1 is '28 months later'. 2 is the death of Barry Howard. 3 and 4 could just be the dates concatenated with each other. These seem like pretty recent events (for 2 and 3)

Comment: Location sounds right to me just due to OP's [other puzzle](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/31540/what-is-my-name-simple-puzzle)...

Comment: very close, correct path.

Comment: Perhaps based on clue and method of death for #59, the number 150 should be in there?

Comment: What's that word 'dot' doing in the second clue?  Is that indicating a decimal point?  Should we use 78 for degrees rather than 28?  That would give us Canadian Islands, Greenland, Svalbard and Bolshevik Island in Russia.

Comment: @chronoD is very close, but I want the exact name of the town, village, city or whatever

Comment: @patient-zero the nearest location is Dhaulagiri II. Is that what you're looking for, or am I off on the coordinates by a bit?

Comment: @ChronoD that's the name of the mountain there, off by a bit

Answer (score 1):

Tweaking the coordinates provided in ChronoD's answer a bit, you get to:

> **Hotel Xanadu** near **Jomsom Airport** in **Nepal**
>  28.78150186 N (using 150 for the number of times victim #59 was stabbed, also the Ford F-150)
>  83.72359812 E (using 723 instead of 34 for the USS WALKE clue)
>  So Jessica's in Xanadu, because she's a huge Orson Welles/Olivia Newton-John fan?